# Writing results from "desribe" into a matrix changed the Matrix in R-Studio from Data to Value

Tags: r, matrix, tapply, describe

I learning since 1 month "r" und working with r-Studio. Now I have following Problem:

I want to describe a Dataset with the function "describe". After that, I want to write the results into a table, defined with the function Matrix. 
I write this table into a variable "Result_table <- matrix(nrwo = 2, ncol = 7). 
But when I want to write e result of the "describe" function in my "Result_table" it changed in the Global Environment from Data into Values an i only have a list - no table.

If use the function "tapply", I don't habe this Problem. I have my defined result in my defined table cell.

Is it not possible to write results from the "describe" function into a table deescribed with the Matrix function?

Comment: As the problem may lay in your 'describe' function or in the way you write the results of the function into the matrix, a reproducible example would be helpful since in R there's multiple way to do the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. The Code is following:

```
#Package
library("psych")

#Table
Results <- Matrix(nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
colnames(Results) <- c("mean","sd")
rownames(Results) <- c("2010","2011")
View(Results)

#Calculate mean
mean2010 <- describe(sba$SalesNet[sba$Year=="2010")
mean2011 <- describe(sba$SalesNet[sba$Year=="2011")
(mean2010[3])
(mean2010[4])
(mean2011[3])
(mean2011[4])

#Writing Results
Results[1,1] <- mean2010[3]
Results[2,1] <- mean2011[3]
Results[1,2] <- mean2010[4]
Results[2,2] <- mean2011[4]
View(Results)
```